# How to create a list of sameDate in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of maps with two fields: 'Image Url' ,'DateCreated' . ( They are fetched from Firebase :

What I'm trying to do is , display all the photos where date_created is the same .For instance:

Today (Date_Created ) : there is  3 images with the same date.

Thanks for the help

```
 [{imgUrl: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sweet-1c314.appspot.com/o/files%2F49786da9-d72e-44b5-9ec6-f444d7385f427015259517723278159.jpg?alt=media&token=4e399b3f-1aaf-4c52-9e6e-23bd519614a7, dateCreated: 1678233600000}, {imgUrl: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sweet-1c314.appspot.com/o/files%2Feacf1805-034e-4a18-9b2c-3c1418c3542b7704313797850757353.jpg?alt=media&token=2dc5882b-ae55-40a4-8894-eb656108c717, dateCreated: 1676505600000},],
```

My code :

```
  class SugarPhotoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SugarPhotoPage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<SugarPhotoPage> createState() => _SugarPhotoPageState();
}

class _SugarPhotoPageState extends State<SugarPhotoPage> {
  final collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('photos');
  late List<Map<String, dynamic>> listOFimages;

  void getData() async {
    late List<Map<String, dynamic>> templistOFimages = [];
    late List<int> listOFDate = [];
    late List<List<String>> listOfSameDateImage = [];
    var data = await collection.get();
    data.docs.forEach((element) {
      templistOFimages.add(element.data());
    });

    templistOFimages.forEach(
      (p) {
        listOFDate.add(p['dateCreated']);
      },
    );
    for (var d in listOFDate) {
      for (var p in templistOFimages) {
        if (p['dateCreated'] == d) {
          listOfSameDateImage.add(p['imgUrl']);
        }
      }
    }
    print(templistOFimages);
    print(listOFDate);
    print(listOfSameDateImage);
    setState(() {
      listOFimages = templistOFimages;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          // SweetList(),
          Container(
            height: 70,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: Text(
              'sdf',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can filter through your `Map` or any `List` by using the `.where` method that allows you to filter your map to get only the values you want.

```dart
void main() {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> jsoninput = [
    {'imgUrl': "mysuperurl", 'dateCreated': 1},
    {'imgUrl': "myothersuperurl", 'dateCreated': 2},
    {'imgUrl': "anothersuperurl", 'dateCreated': 1}
  ];



  //Here the value you want;
  int filterBy = jsoninput.first['dateCreated']; 
  print(jsoninput.where((element) => element['dateCreated'] == filterBy));

  // RESULT:
  // ({imgUrl: mysuperurl, dateCreated: 1}, {imgUrl: anothersuperurl, dateCreated: 1})
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, The problem with this approach is. it gives just images with dateCreated: 1.
I have a pageview, where every page shows the photos of the day. 
Page 1: Image taken on date 1  . Page 2 : image taken on date 2 .......
With this approach, i just get  one date

Comment: What i did was ,1.  create a list of date . 2. Loop through map to check if datecreated  is on the list of date if so it will add to list of list of string (images)  where those images have same datecreated.